# Using AFHTTPRequestOperation in XCTests

Tags: objective-c, ios8, afnetworking, xctest

I have the following test case code:

```
- (void)testExample {
    // URL https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=album%3AJustified%20artist%3AJustin%20Timberlake&type=album


    dispatch_semaphore_t sem = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
    [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager] GET:@"https://api.spotify.com/v1/search"
                                      parameters:@{@"q":@"album:Justified artist:Justin Timberlake",
                                                   @"type":@"album"}
                                         success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                                             dispatch_semaphore_signal(sem);
                                         } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

                                         }
     ];
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(sem, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

    // This is an example of a functional test case.
    XCTAssert(YES, @"Pass");
}
```

I was expecting the test case to block and wait for the http request to finish.
The strange thing is that the `AFHTTPRequestOperation` never reaches the success block even the url is a valid one. 
If I use the following code outside XCTest, it won't happen, the success block will be executed.
Has anyone has seen this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of observations:

1. Your test is freezing because AFNetworking dispatches its completion blocks to the main queue. But you've blocked the main thread with the `dispatch_semaphore_wait`, resulting in a deadlock.

   You can resolve this by setting the manager's `completionQueue` to be a global queue for the purposes of the test, thus eliminating the deadlock caused by the semaphore on the main thread:

   ```
   - (void)testExample {
       dispatch_semaphore_t sem = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

       AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

       manager.completionQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

       [manager GET:@"https://api.spotify.com/v1/search" parameters:@{@"q":@"album:Justified artist:Justin Timberlake", @"type":@"album"} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
           XCTAssert(YES, @"Pass"); // you might want more rigorous test of results here

           dispatch_semaphore_signal(sem);
       } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
           XCTFail(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);

           dispatch_semaphore_signal(sem);
       }];

       dispatch_semaphore_wait(sem, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
   }
   ```
2. Note, nowadays one would use `XCTestExpectation` to perform asynchronous tests. This eliminates the need for the semaphore and, coincidentally, resolves the deadlock issue, too:

   ```
   - (void)testExample {
       XCTestExpectation *expectation = [self expectationWithDescription:@"asynchronous request"];

       AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

       [manager GET:@"https://api.spotify.com/v1/search" parameters:@{@"q":@"album:Justified artist:Justin Timberlake", @"type":@"album"} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
           XCTAssert(YES, @"Pass"); // you might want more rigorous test of results here

           [expectation fulfill];
       } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
           XCTFail(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);

           [expectation fulfill];
       }];

       [self waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:30.0 handler:nil];
   }
   ```
3. By the way, whether you use `XCTestExpectation` or semaphore, make sure that both the success and failure blocks both satisfy the expectation/semaphore.

Comment: Yes, I figured the second solution works me. Thank you